# Stock chart using PHP

Tags: php, charts, stock, candlestick-chart

I would like to do something similar to this site 
http://finviz.com/

Basically, when you move a mouseover on stock symbol, it show a stock chart using image generated from backend. For example:
http://finviz.com/chart.ashx?s=m&p=d&t=RAX

My question is how to do this backend functionality using PHP. I am thinking of 2 things:
1. Ability to generate candle stick chart. I think I can use something like http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html#candlestick_charts
AND
2. Data source. I think the source can come from manual extraction somewhere for the daily price.

Does anyone know existing library? I don't want to do Flash but just .gif or .jpg image or HTML5. If not, look like I have to build this myself. Any suggestion to make things easier is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

ChartDirector has various charting options for both technical and fundamental charting of financial data:
http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery_finance.html

If you are looking for commercial solution, it can be a very good option.

Answer (score 1):

Try pchart:

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yah I checked. There is no candle stick type of graph for stock chart http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=pChart